# How to add effects in images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I came across a library at https://svgdotjs.github.io/. I know there may be answers at many places. But couldn't find the algorithm on how to add effects in images using javaScript. I want effects like negative, copper, retro etc...
I really tried hard to understand the algorithm and googled it as well. what I found is image processing and all. 
My question actually is that what pixel manipulation is done for which effect?
Lets say for gray-scale photo, you have to just add level of grey as per the value of RGB. Similar algo should be there for copper or other effects.

Comment: Other than SVG, you might also want to check out how adding effects with `canvas` work. Here is a great library for that http://www.pixastic.com/lib/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at the examples on the library website ?
Go to https://svgdotjs.github.io/plugins/svg-filter-js/ , right click on the page -> "View page source".
You can now see the supported effects and how to use them.